# What is the difference between llblgen and nHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, orm, llblgenpro

What are the key differences between llblgen and nHibernate?

Comment: I am sure if you searched in stackoverflow for llbl and nhibernate you will get a lot of answers, also look this: http://shrinkrays.net/articles/a-look-at-dotnet-orms.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [nHibernate versus LLBLGen Pro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114215/nhibernate-versus-llblgen-pro)

Comment: Amr's comment link is now at http://www.anotherchris.net/orm/a-look-at-net-orms-part-3/#lllbgen

Answer (score 4):

LLBLGen is an exquisitely case hardened tool that generates ultimately extensible code. Customer service is second to none and bugs are fixed as they are found by one of the finest minds in the business. I have had 5 hour turnarounds on obscure, affecting only me, bugs.

I am currently cutting my teeth on nhibernate and have to say that the apprehension that kept me from it for so long was not misplaced. It is a great tool with a huge user base but inherently, the mapping file / mapping classes / mapping attributes strategy is at the same time soft and brittle.

This is my opinion, no need for punitive downvotes because I am criticizing nhibernate.

Answer (score 3):

LLblgen is a commercial tool, it uses designer based configuration to generate the classes for data access.

Nhibernate is an open source free tool that uses xml based mapping files to map your objects to the tables in the database.

I prefer Nhibernate over LLblgen.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that Fluent NHibernate supports setting up mapping in code.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the overview page of llblgen's homepage:

**LLBLGen Pro, the #1 O/R mapper and data-access tier generator for .NET, generates a complete data-access tier and business façade/support tier for you (in C# or VB.NET), using an existing database schema set. In seconds. The generated .NET code is compiler-ready and can, being compiled by the .NET C# or VB.NET compiler, be used immediately by other applications.**

So yes, its an ORM mapper as well, plus loads more.